# Find the limit of $\sin(3x) / \ln x$ as x approaches zero from the right

Tags: calculus, limits

For my answer key it said 0, but it doesn't give me an explanation. I hoped that someone here can give me an explanation so I can understand this concept!

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\ln x}=$

Comment: L'Hopital's Rule does not apply here. What is the limit of the numerator? Of the denominator?

Comment: My professor won't let anyone use that rule. We automatically receive a 0 if we do use it.

Comment: When you graph the numerator and denominator seperately, you can see what is going on.

Comment: Oh I see how it works now! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln x=-\infty,
$$
which you should know, and
$$
-\frac{1}{\ln x}\le\frac{\sin 3x}{\ln x}\le\frac{1}{\ln x},
$$
the squeeze theorem tells you the limit is $0$.